# Why would you import .scss into .js?

Tags: javascript, sass

I am trying to understand some JavaScript source code and at the top of the .js file I am seeing this:

```
import './style.scss';
```

I'm already confused. Sass is supposed to be converted to CSS. JavaScript and CSS are typically completely separate. Why would you import Sass into JavaScript?

Comment: https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/sxbrscjuqu-share-scss-variables-with-javascript

Comment: So that Webpack can find it: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/ -> https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/ -> https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/

Comment: Why don't ya'll post answers?

Comment: @mkaatman but...why? If you have styles defined in (S)CSS you should be applying a style through classes and others in order to match a selector. Then let the CSS engine handle it, instead of adding inline styles. Seems like yet another step back with how some developers think about CSS.

Comment: It is popular within react where you treat the styles as if they belong to a component. I think it comes down to personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into JSX and React:
https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

JSX is an extension of Javascript that allows you to add HTML code.
You wouldn't import Sass into a javascript file, you would import it in a JSX file and use it to link an element to a particular className.